# The order of array elements when calling .to_a of Struct object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

`.to_a` of Struct object returns an array of its attribute values.
How are the array elements ordered?
It seems to be the definition order of attributes when running `Struct.new`, but I don't have much confidence.

```
S = Struct.new :foo, :bar, :baz
# => S
s = S.new 1, 2, 3
# => #<struct S foo=1, bar=2, baz=3>
s.to_a
# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Any idea?

Comment: IDK but if it's not documented ([`Struct#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-i-to_a)) then probably it's not worth relying on the order. Why do you need this? Maybe we can suggest a better way.

Comment: As far as I know, a) attributes are held in a `RHASH_TBL`; b) `RHASH_TBL` is the structure that backs Ruby `Hash`; c) `Hash` iterates keys in insertion order; d) `Struct` initialises attributes in the order specified in the constructor arguments. One might want to re-check my premises, but I conclude there is a basis to be confident about your conclusion. But I agree that a better way might make sense, as most of the above is undocumented.

Comment: If you examine the doc for [Struct#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html#method-i-values_at) you‘ll see that `s.values_at(0,1,2) #=> [1,2,3]`. I therefore believe that `to_a` will return the same array, though that is not documented. You could of course use `values_at` in place of `to_a`.

Comment: Thank you. What I actually want to do is to generate a CSV using `Struct` with `keyword_init`, just like: `csv_obj << MYSTRUCT.new(date: Date.today, user_id: 2, amount: 200).to_a`. The values must be written in the specific order (`date`, `user_id`, and `amount`). Maybe should take another way because that is undocumented behavior?

Comment: @bravejohnny _"What I actually want to do is to generate a CSV"_ – Ruby comes with a [`CSV`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. It might already do what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I'm using CSV class, and looking for a better way to push data to a CSV object.

Comment: As @CarySwoveland says, I'm almost 100% certain `to_a` is fine. In fact, you don't even need it: `CSV.generate { |csv| csv << S.members << s }` does exactly what you intended..